# How to send a request using client-side javascript to a server with specific port?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, request

The question might not describe actually my problem.
So I have a a host A. I want to send a request with a payload using js in html page. The destination is another Host B. Host B is on another network and I want it to receive the request from A. I don't know how to do that.
I tried setting up a simple python server that just prints the request:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((localhost, PORT)) ## localhost: 127.0.0.1 and random port
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
with conn:
    print('Connected by', addr)
    data = ""
    while True:
        data += conn.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
    print(data)
```

I feel like this is very wrong. Anyway, on A I tried to send a get request using fetch api:

```
fetch(`http://${public_ip_of_B}:${port_of_B}/${payload}`)
```

The request remains on pending status and throws an error.

So how can I send the request from A to B?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `fetch()` uses the HTTP protocol, you can't just send raw data.

Comment: I thought I could receive the string "GET HTTP1.1...". Something like that. But now I just came across websockets. Are there any good for my situation. Thanks :)

Comment: The Python code needs to send back a properly formatted HTTP response.

Comment: WebSockets is appropriate for a long-lived connection between the browser and server, where they send information back and forth and can maintain state of the connection. We use it our game application.

Comment: So If I change the python code to send an HTTP response back, would it fix it? I didn't even get the request?

Comment: You shouldn't bind to `localhost`. That will only allow requests from the same machine, not a remote client.

Comment: should I bind it to the public ip?

Comment: @EyePatch: *"I thought I could receive the string "GET HTTP1.1..."."* - you could. But you only print what you received after the client has closed the connection and the client will only close the connection after the server has closed it after sending the response but your server does not even start reading the response since it is still reading from the client. Please read the actual HTTP standard instead of (wrongly) second-guessing how this works.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will look into it more

Comment: When using fetch, is `fetch("http://publicIP:PORT").then(res=>console.log(res))` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind to `localhost`. To accept connections from anywhere, use an empty string for the host address when binding.

```
s.bind(('', PORT))
```